# E/Volley: [10767] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://ip/url.php

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, xampp, android-volley

Estoy haciendo una app móvil parecida a Uber eats pero me he estancado en la parte de conectar a base de datos, quiero hacer un signup conectado vía `MySQL (XAMPP)` pero me da un error a la hora de querer ejecutar el ingreso de datos.

Cabe destacar que yo tengo dos discos duros y he visto que el volley me lo llama del disco secundario (E) mientras todo lo demás del disco del sistema (C) no se si eso este afectando algo...

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txt_User,txt_Pass,txt_ConfPass,txt_Email;
    Button sig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        txt_User=findViewById(R.id.txt_User);
        txt_Pass=findViewById(R.id.txt_Pass);
        txt_ConfPass=findViewById(R.id.txt_ConfPass);
        txt_Email=findViewById(R.id.txt_Email);

        Explode explode = new Explode();
        explode.setDuration(500);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
        sig = findViewById(R.id.btn_Next);

        sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ingresarUsuario("http://ip/metrofood/insertar_usuario.php");
                startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, Data.class));
            }
        });
    }


    private void ingresarUsuario(String URL)
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("nombreUsu",txt_User.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("passUsu",txt_Pass.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("emailUsu",txt_Email.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("idRol","2");
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}

Error en consola: 

D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
    *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248

Error-> E/Volley: [10767] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://ip/metrofood/insertar_usuario.php

D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0

D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
```

Comment: El error 404 indica que la URL es incorrecta. Debes revisar que ese archivo existe realmente en esa URL: `http://ip/url.php` Eso lo puedes comprobar incluso desde el mismo navegador. A Volley le debes indicar una URL válida para que funcione.

Comment: Yo tenia el mismo problema. Habia hecho el archivo insertar.php desde el WordPad y se ve q cuando modifique el nombre del archivo me quedo insertar.php.php y ese era el error. Solo renombre el archivo de la forma correcta y listo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu programa intenta realizar una petición POST a una URL usando Volley, el problema es simplemente que esa url no existe:

Error-> E/Volley: [10767] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://ip/metrofood/insertar_usuario.php

> [HTTP 404](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) Not Found o HTTP 404 No encontrado es un código de
>   estado HTTP que indica que el host ha sido capaz de comunicarse con el
>   servidor

---

Probablemente tengas otros problemas pero primeramente asegura que la url funciona adecuadamente.

Comment: Como puedo probar que mi url funcione correctamente?

Comment: @M.Argumedo el administrador del sitio debe asegurar que este disponible, no será que la ip es incorrecta?

Comment: Debo ocupar mi ip publica o privada?

Comment: Eso depende de donde quieras realizar la petición, ¿tu aplicación funcionará en una determinada red?, pero lo importante es que pueda tu aplicación pueda leer esta url sin problema.

Comment: La aplicacion actualmente busco que funcione dentro de mi misma red (la misma de la pc con el xampp) entonces utilice la publica, dado que con la privada ni siquiera me conectaba a nada.